# Should Prepros work to compile my SASS to CSS on a Github.io page? If so, what could be causing my SASS styling to not work on the Github.io page?

Tags: css, sass, github-pages, prepros

My project is styled just as I want it to be locally. After pushing it to GitHub and all the files appear to be present I published it to a GitHub.io page and none of my stylings are present.

Have I fundamentally misunderstood the purpose and use of Prepros or am I making some other mistake? What info do you need to determine what the issue is?

My prepros-6.config file

```
 {
  "name": "landingPage",
  "firstRun": false,
  "exportConfig": true,
  "fileConfigs": [
    {
      "path": "styles/style.sass",
      "configJson": "{\"forceCompile\":false,\"customOutput\":\"styles/style.css\",\"autoCompile\":true,\"sourceMap\":false,\"compiler-node-sass\":{\"enabled\":true,\"outputStyle\":\"nested\"},\"compiler-autoprefixer\":{\"enabled\":true},\"compiler-minify-css\":{\"enabled\":false}}"
    }
  ],
  "fileTree": {
    "expandedDirs": [],
    "hideSystemFiles": true,
    "systemFiles": [
      ".*",
      "desktop.ini",
      "prepros.config",
      "$RECYCLE.BIN",
      "prepros.cfg",
      "prepros-6.config",
      "Prepros Export"
    ],
    "hideUnwatchedFiles": false
  },
  "imports": [
    {
      "path": "styles/style.sass",
      "imports": [
        "styles/_colors.sass"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "projectView": {
    "selectedView": "file-tree"
  },
  "fileWatcher": {
    "enabled": true,
    "watchedExtensions": [
      "less",
      "sass",
      "scss",
      "styl",
      "md",
      "markdown",
      "coffee",
      "js",
      "jade",
      "haml",
      "slim",
      "ls",
      "kit",
      "png",
      "jpg",
      "jpeg",
      "ts",
      "pug",
      "css",
      "html",
      "htm",
      "php"
    ]
  },
  "pathFilters": [
    "node_modules",
    ".*",
    "bower_components",
    "prepros.config",
    "Prepros Export",
    "prepros-6.config",
    "prepros.cfg",
    "wp-admin",
    "wp-includes"
  ],
  "server": {
    "port": 7887,
    "assignNewPortAutomatically": true,
    "enable": true,
    "proxy": {
      "enable": false,
      "url": ""
    }
  },
  "browser-sync": {
    "enable": false,
    "clicks": true,
    "forms": true,
    "scroll": true
  },
  "live-reload": {
    "enable": true,
    "animate": true,
    "delay": 0
  },
  "ftp-deploy": {
    "connectionType": "ftp",
    "remotePath": "",
    "uploadTimeout": 20000,
    "uploadOnChange": false,
    "ftp": {
      "secure": false,
      "host": "",
      "port": 21,
      "user": "",
      "password": ""
    },
    "sftp": {
      "host": "",
      "port": 22,
      "usePrivateKey": false,
      "username": "",
      "password": "",
      "privateKey": "",
      "passphrase": ""
    },
    "pathFilters": [
      "config.rb",
      "prepros.config",
      "prepros-6.config",
      "node_modules",
      "Prepros Export",
      ".git",
      ".idea",
      ".sass-cache",
      ".hg",
      ".svn",
      ".cache",
      ".DS_Store",
      "*.sass",
      "*.scss",
      "*.less",
      "*.pug",
      "*.jade",
      "*.styl",
      "*.haml",
      "*.slim",
      "*.coffee",
      "*.ls",
      "*.kit",
      "*.ts"
    ],
    "history": []
  },
  "file-type-sass": "{\"compilers\":[\"node-sass\",\"autoprefixer\",\"minify-css\"]}",
  "file-type-less": "{\"compilers\":[\"less\",\"autoprefixer\",\"minify-css\"]}",
  "autoprefixer": {
    "browsers": "last 5 versions"
  },
  "file-type-pug": "{\"compilers\":[\"pug\"]}",
  "file-type-css": "{\"compilers\":[\"autoprefixer\",\"cssnext\",\"minify-css\"]}",
  "file-type-javascript": "{\"compilers\":[\"concat-js\",\"babel\",\"uglify-js\"]}",
  "file-type-stylus": "{\"compilers\":[\"stylus\",\"autoprefixer\",\"minify-css\"]}",
  "file-type-markdown": "{\"compilers\":[\"markdown\"]}",
  "file-type-haml": "{\"compilers\":[\"haml\"]}",
  "file-type-slim": "{\"compilers\":[\"slim\"]}",
  "file-type-coffee-script": "{\"compilers\":[\"coffee-script\",\"uglify-js\"]}",
  "file-type-livescript": "{\"compilers\":[\"livescript\",\"uglify-js\"]}",
  "file-type-kit": "{\"compilers\":[\"kit\"]}",
  "uglify-js": {
    "ie8": false,
    "compress": {
      "sequences": true,
      "properties": true,
      "dead_code": true,
      "drop_debugger": true,
      "unsafe": false,
      "unsafe_comps": false,
      "unsafe_math": false,
      "unsafe_proto": false,
      "unsafe_regexp": false,
      "conditionals": true,
      "comparisons": true,
      "evaluate": true,
      "booleans": true,
      "loops": true,
      "unused": true,
      "toplevel": false,
      "top_retain": "",
      "hoist_funs": true,
      "hoist_vars": false,
      "if_return": true,
      "join_vars": true,
      "cascade": true,
      "collapse_vars": true,
      "reduce_vars": true,
      "warnings": true,
      "negate_iife": true,
      "pure_getters": false,
      "pure_funcs": [],
      "drop_console": false,
      "expression": false,
      "keep_fargs": true,
      "keep_fnames": false,
      "passes": 1,
      "keep_infinity": false,
      "side_effects": true,
      "global_defs": []
    },
    "output": {
      "ascii_only": false,
      "beautify": false,
      "bracketize": false,
      "comments": "",
      "indent_level": 4,
      "indent_start": 0,
      "inline_script": false,
      "keep_quoted_props": false,
      "max_line_len": false,
      "preamble": "",
      "preserve_line": false,
      "quote_keys": false,
      "quote_style": 0,
      "semicolons": true,
      "shebang": true,
      "width": 80
    }
  },
  "cssnext": {
    "customProperties": true,
    "applyRule": true,
    "calc": false,
    "nesting": true,
    "customMedia": true,
    "mediaQueriesRange": true,
    "customSelectors": true,
    "attributeCaseInsensitive": true,
    "colorRebeccapurple": true,
    "colorHwb": true,
    "colorGray": true,
    "colorHexAlpha": true,
    "colorFunction": true,
    "fontVariant": true,
    "filter": true,
    "initial": true,
    "rem": true,
    "pseudoElements": true,
    "pseudoClassMatches": true,
    "pseudoClassNot": true,
    "pseudoClassAnyLink": true,
    "colorRgba": true,
    "overflowWrap": true
  },
  "file-type-typescript": "{\"compilers\":[\"typescript\",\"uglify-js\"]}",
  "babel": {
    "useBabelRc": true,
    "presets": {
      "babel-preset-es2015": true
    },
    "plugins": {
      "babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": true,
      "babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx": true,
      "babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator": true,
      "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": true,
      "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": true
    }
  },
  "file-type-png": "{\"compilers\":[\"png\"]}",
  "file-type-jpg": "{\"compilers\":[\"jpg\"]}"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Github pages only serve static files (*.html, *.css, *.js). Github pages allow for the use of a static site generator [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com). This way you can push the project to Github and will build.

If you are pushing code to Github hoping to compile your SASS file with Prepros that won't happen. You have to compile on your machine and push that static files to Github.

Github can explain it better than I can [here on pages.github.com](https://pages.github.com/)

Comment: The CSS file is already there compiled prior to pushing to Github and the src in the header on my HTML page is the CSS file. Could the SASS or prepros-6.config be interfering somehome?

Comment: It shouldn't interfere. Is there a console error on the page? If so, what does it display?

Answer (score 0):

No Github pages will not process sass with prepros. It can only do this with [jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/).

But [here](https://lenocam.github.io/landing-page/), you're problem is that path to your css resolves to a 404 page.

```
https://lenocam.github.io/landing-page/ + /styles/style.css

= 404 on https://lenocam.github.io/styles/style.css
```

Try to call your css with a relative path :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/style.css">
```

Same for your images. eg:

```
<img src="./images/barrels.jpg" alt="">
```